# C# Regex.Match curly brackets- contents only? (exclude braces)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've been unable to find an answer on this: can I use the `Regex.Matches` method to return only the *contents* of items with curly braces?

If I use the Regex `({[^}]*})` my `MatchCollection` values includes the braces. I want to match, but then only return the contents. Here's what I have so far:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(({[^}]*}), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches("Test {Token1} {Token 2}");
// Results include braces (undesirable)
var results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I always liked it explicit. So you can use "positive lookbehind" (?<=...) and "positive lookahead" (?=...) groups:

```
(?<=\{)
[^}]*
(?=\})
```

which means:

- require opening curly bracket **before** match
- collect text (of, course) - as commented before I may be [^{}]* as well
- require closing curly bracket **after** match

Comment: Yes, so the full `(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})` Regex appears to work well. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In C#, as in many other programming language, the regex engine supports ***capturing groups***, that are *submatches*, parts of substrings that match a whole regex pattern, defined in a regex pattern with the help of parentheses (e.g. `1([0-9])3` will match `123` and save the value of `2` into a capture group 1 buffer). Captured texts are accessed via [`Match.Groups[n].Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) where *n* is the index of the capture group inside the pattern.

**Capturing is much more effecient that lookarounds**. Whenever there is no need for complex conditions, capturing groups are much better alternatives.

See my regex speed test performed at regexhero.net:

[image]

Now, *how can we get the substring inside curly braces*?

- if there is no other curly braces inside, with *a negated character class*: `{([^{}]*)`
- if there can be nested curly brackets: `{((?>[^{}]+|{(?<c>)|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))`

In both cases, we match an opening `{`, and then match (1) any character other than `{` or `}`, or (2) any characters up to the first paired `}`.

Here is [sample code](https://ideone.com/iIZ7rT):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("Test {Token1} {Token 2}", @"{([^{}]*)");
var results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).Distinct().ToList();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", results));
matches = Regex.Matches("Test {Token1} {Token {2}}", @"{((?>[^{}]+|{(?<c>)|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))");
results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).Distinct().ToList();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", results));
```

Result: `Token1, Token 2`, `Token1, Token {2}`.

Note that `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is redundant when you have no literal letters that can have different case in the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Milosz Krajewski, Nothing to add but here is the function

```
private List<String> GetTokens(String str)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(str);

    // Results include braces (undesirable)
    return matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but maybe this should be merged with  [@Milosz Krajewski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16538131/5876282)

Answer (score 3):

Just move the braces outside the parentheses:

```
 {([^}]*)}
```

Comment: Should the set `[^}]` be modified to to `[^{}]`? Right now the regular expression also matches `{{{Hello}`, doesn't it?

Comment: The `regex.Matches` method still returns the values with braces.

Comment: @PeterX: You need to look at the `Captures` of the `Matches`.  The captures contain the pieces between the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It is regex for C# .net.

```
@"{(.*?)}"
```

it display a

token1
token2

Comment: This results in a `match.Value` containing **also** the curly brackets. Which is exactly what the author of the question would like to avoid

Answer (score 1):

Little bit modifying the answer of @Milosz Krajewski

```
(?<=\{)[^}{]*(?=\})
```

this will skip the middle single opening and closing Curly braces in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want. Change the regex to `{([^}]*)}`. That will only capture the text between {}, not including them.

Comment: This regex results in an error: `parsing "{([^]*)}" - Unterminated [] set.`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the regex tips! I know that this is not the answer to the original question but in case it helps someone else, I created this string extension method based on all your recommendations so I can replace localized string constants.

```
/// <summary>
/// Replace all the text in curly brackets with the parameters by
/// order it apears in the text.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>This is to be use with const string that cannot be 
/// interpolated with $ or String.Format.</remarks>
/// <param name="text">The text that contains string in curly 
/// brackets.</param>
/// <param name="replaceTexts">The list of replace texts ordered as 
/// it apear in the <paramref name="text"/></param>
/// <returns>The interpolated text where string in curly brackets 
/// are replaced with the replaceTexts parameters.</returns>
public static string ReplaceText(this string text, params string[] replaceTexts)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return text;
    
    // Found all {TextToReplace} and results includes curlybraket 
    // so we can use string.Replace
    var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"{(.*?)}");            
    var results = matches.Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().ToList();
    
    // Nothing to replace in the text, just return it
    if(!results.Any()) return text;
    
    // The number of element to replace must match 
    // the replaceTexts parameter
    if(results.Count() != replaceTexts.Count())
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(replaceTexts), "The text must conaints the exact same number of curly brackets string to replace than the replaceTexts parameters.");
    }

    var index = 0;
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        text = text.Replace(result, replaceTexts[index++]);
    }

    return text;
}
```

Usage:

```
public const string MyConstantString = "Replace {thisText} with {otherText}";
MyConstantString.ReplaceText("first parameter", "second parameter");
```

The above result will be "Replace first parameter with second parameter".

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31481942)