# Spliting string into array based on curly brackets

Tags: c#, arrays, string, strsplit

For Example I have String like this:

> ""dear customer{Customer name} your reference number is {referenceNumber}"

I want to get array=["{Customer name}",{referenceNumber}]"

I have to split based on curly bracket inside bracket value is changeable means it can be different for different cases I just need to split and get array of value inside brackets including brackets.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your effort so far and include details about the actual problem being faced.

Comment: i just want to get array=["{Customer name}",{referenceNumber}]"
from above given string in question@tnw

Comment: I'm aware. Read my comment again please.

Comment: What you are asking for is unlikely to help you to achieve the goal to implement templates... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854418/how-to-replace-curly-braces-and-its-contents-in-a-string (and many similar question) show what you should be doing...

Comment: thanks, @AlexeiLevenkov the same thing i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, splitting on { and } will produce an array where every odd index is what you want..

```
.Split('{','}').Where((s,i)=>i%2==1).Select(s=>'{' + s + '}').ToArray();
```

Split the string, use the LINQ Where function that passes the int index to the predicate, insist that the index be odd (mod2 is 1) and select a new string that puts the brackets back on, ToArray