# identifying and extracting (showing)errors from words

Tags: c#

need to identify "errors" in text files and show them in console 
need help with the regex and extracting only the error out of the text as now it shows the full text.

text i need to identify is in brackets
Pay us 2 Bitcoins now to:
{ 18RJA5BpFe4CGDFQG59jLNhPqYCRaEFng1 }

```cs
Regex finderror = new Regex(@"\W+\d{,15}");
DirectoryInfo id = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\student_copy\\text");
FileInfo[] fiArrrr = id.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo f in fiArrrr)
{
    string stuff = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName);
    Match errortext = finderror.Match(stuff);
    if (errortext.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("no error for file ",);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you to match everything inside curly brackets?

Comment: Can there be more than one error per file?

Comment: there is only one per file @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Regex Here from Milosz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16538131/2330053).

Your code, slightly modified:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex finderror = new Regex(@"(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})");
    DirectoryInfo id = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\student_copy\\text");
    FileInfo[] fiArrrr = id.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo f in fiArrrr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + f.FullName);
        string stuff = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName);
        Match errortext = finderror.Match(stuff);
        if (errortext.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Found:");
            Console.WriteLine(errortext.Value.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No error for file.");
        }
    }
    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```