# C# Finding specific values from messageformat strings

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching, messageformat

Given a messageformat string such as `str` below. I want to be able to get the "notifications" & "name" values which are used to display the text values.

```
var str = @"You have {notifications, plural,
          zero {no notifications}
           one {one notification}
           =42 {a universal amount of notifications}
         other {# notifications}
        }. Have a nice day, {name}!";
```

I have tried using a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537901/c-sharp-regex-match-curly-brackets-contents-only-exclude-braces) such as:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"{(.*?)}");
//var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=\{)[^}{]*(?=\})");
var results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

But the above does not take in to account that `{notifications,..` is itself wraped in curly braces and includes the inner values that are not needed, which are wrapped in curly braces also.

So in brief I just want to be able to parse a string such as `str` above and get `notifications` & `name` at the returned values.

A string such as `var str2 = @"Hello {name}"` should just return `name` as the value.

**EDIT**

The values `notifications` & `name` will not be known in advance - I have just used this as an example, for the values I require to return from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR: Here is an optional solution

```
var str = @"You have {notifications, plural,
          zero {no notifications}
           one {one notification}
           =42 {a universal amount of notifications}
         other {# notifications}
        }. Have a nice day, {name}!";

// get matches skipping nested curly braces
var matches = 
    Regex.Matches(str, @"{((?:[^{}]|(?<counter>{)|(?<-counter>}))+(?(counter)(?!)))}");

var results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).Distinct()
    .Select(v => Regex.Match(v, @"^\w+").Value) // take 1st word
    .ToList();
```

**which results in** (copied from Visual Studio Locals window while debugging)

```
results Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
    [0] "notifications"
    [1] "name"
```

... original answer follows ...

---

One thing to note about the current solution in the original question:

- the use of `.` doesn't match line breaks, so that's one reason why it currently matches the nested values (see this [source](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html))

#### If I understand your goal, this article is a nice explanation and demonstration of a related problem and solution:

(this article addresses the main challenge noted in the original question--the **nested curly braces**)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timart/2013/05/14/nestedrecursive-regex-and-net-balancing-groups-detect-a-function-with-a-regex/

#### From that article, I'd suggest the below pattern as an optional solution:

```
var str = @"You have {notifications, plural,
          zero {no notifications}
           one {one notification}
           =42 {a universal amount of notifications}
         other {# notifications}
        }. Have a nice day, {name}!";

// get matches skipping nested curly braces
var matches = 
    Regex.Matches(str, @"{((?:[^{}]|(?<counter>{)|(?<-counter>}))+(?(counter)(?!)))}");
var results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

**which results in** (copied from Visual Studio Locals window while debugging)

```
results Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
    [0] "notifications, plural,\r\n          zero {no notifications}\r\n           one {one notification}\r\n           =42 {a universal amount of notifications}\r\n         other {# notifications}\r\n        "
    [1] "name"
```

(or if you were to print these results to the console):

```
// Result 0 would look like:
notifications, plural,
          zero {no notifications}
           one {one notification}
           =42 {a universal amount of notifications}
         other {# notifications}


// Result 1 would look like:
name
```

---

## Update

I came back to this and realized that the question asked for just the single words as results.

#### Then take the first word from each result

(I'm repeating the above snippet with the additional select statement to show the full solution)

```
var str = @"You have {notifications, plural,
          zero {no notifications}
           one {one notification}
           =42 {a universal amount of notifications}
         other {# notifications}
        }. Have a nice day, {name}!";

// get matches skipping nested curly braces
var matches = 
    Regex.Matches(str, @"{((?:[^{}]|(?<counter>{)|(?<-counter>}))+(?(counter)(?!)))}");

var results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).Distinct()
    .Select(v => Regex.Match(v, @"^\w+").Value) // take 1st word
    .ToList();
```

**which results in** (copied from Visual Studio Locals window while debugging)

```
results Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
    [0] "notifications"
    [1] "name"
```

---

## A little more information

(I just found this interesting and spent a little more time researching/learning and thought it worth including some more related information)

Conversations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) include some opinions for and against using regex for this type of problem.

- I think it's interesting to read these opinions and get a more well-rounded point of view

Regardless of the above opinions, .NET creators deemed it appropriate to implement **balancing group definitions**--a functionality this answer uses:

- from Microsoft: [balancing group definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing-group-definitions)
- related source: [Matching Nested Constructs with Balancing Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to write a method that will format a string for you based on an input `count` and the singular (and plural) form of the string:

```
private static string FormatWord(int count, string singluar)
{
    return Format(count, singluar, singluar + "s");
}

private static string FormatWord(int count, string singular, string plural)
{
    return count == 0 ? "no " + plural
        : count == 1 ? "one " + singular
        : count == 42 ? "a universal number of " + plural
        : count + " " + plural;
}
```

Then in use it might look like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var name = "User";

    while (true)
    {
        var count = GetIntFromUser("Enter notification count: ");
        Console.WriteLine($"You have {FormatWord(count, "notification")}. " + 
            $"Have a nice day, {name}");
    }
}
```

Note that this method is also using a helper method to get a strongly-typed integer from the user:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
             !(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    return result;
}

private static void ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(int cursorTop, string message)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```