# Regex every character except one

Tags: regex

Is there regex to catch every character except one?
For instance every characters in curly brackets until open curly bracket is found, then don't match that. For instance catch:

```
{lorem ipsuem}
```

but not:

```
{lorem ipsum {lorem}
```

because there is another `{` within
I've tried different solution like:

```
\{[^\}].+?(?=)\} or \s\{[^\}].+?\s(?!\{)\}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a parser more than a regex.

Comment: can you please clarify your requirements, `{[^{]*}` appears to match what you're asking

Comment: @AD7six yes that is almost that, but for whatever reason if I have {lorem}} it doesn't stop on first } and cath them both

Comment: But in the case of `{lorem ipsum {lorem}`, shouldn't you match `{lorem}`?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson yes I do, but for instance {lorem ipsum {lorem}}, I need only {lorem}, not {lorem}} like it works now

Comment: so use `{[^{}]*}` ? I'm confused what you are wanting to match mostly because of the repeated use of `lorem` - what's a real example of the input string and expected match that doesn't currently work?

Comment: @AD7six yes, {[^{}]*} do the trick! many thanks!

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33936729/3832970) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708840/3832970). The `{[^{}]*}` is common across regex libraries

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your flavour of regex, but something like this `/{[^{}]*\}/` should do the trick.

In your example it matches 
`{lorem ipsuem}`& `{lorem}`.

Do you need to use regex though? looks like a perfect case to use a stack if you're ensuring the braces are balanced.

Comment: thanks, that is almost that, but for whatever reason, if I have {lorem}} it doesn't stop on first } and catch them both

Comment: Try again, I made an edit.

It says match anything between  `{}`except for `{`or `}` zero to many times.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = """{a} {lorem ipsum {lorem}} {b
c}"""

l = re.findall(r'\{[^{}]+\}', s)
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['{a}', '{lorem}', '{b\nc}']
```